# About the Kinect's v2 mics

Tags: kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,
has anybody found any drivers of KInect v2 audio for Ubuntu 12.04??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/204431/about-the-kinect%27s-v2-mics/) by [lefos99](https://answers.ros.org/users/21056/lefos99/) on ROS Answers with karma: 9 on 2015-03-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't know of any solution.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2016-06-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0